# /bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker, anaconda

I'm using image from docker_hub website to build a container to build model deep learning. But when I run this code: `docker run -it --name test_conda continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest bash`. I get an error: `Unable to find image 'continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest' locally latest: Pulling from continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7 33847f680f63: Already exists c3da0b4ad75c: Already exists f2d555b6850d: Already exists 16620cf6431b: Already exists Digest: sha256:d6a6529466ba938f83ea237243e4ca46329d9b68d41e0350f1524ab1432ac304 Status: Downloaded newer image for continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest /bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file`

I don't know how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran your command:

`docker run -it --name test_conda continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest bash`

As I did not already have a related image I got the following output:

```
Trying to pull docker.io/continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 33847f680f63 done  
Copying blob c3da0b4ad75c done  
Copying blob 16620cf6431b done  
Copying blob f2d555b6850d done  
Copying config 036cbb89c6 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
/bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
```

So as we can see, you already had the 1st four layers of the docker image, and that is why you got:

```
33847f680f63: Already exists
c3da0b4ad75c: Already exists
f2d555b6850d: Already exists
16620cf6431b: Already exists
```

Looking into [the original Dockerfile in hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/layers/continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7/latest/images/sha256-d6a6529466ba938f83ea237243e4ca46329d9b68d41e0350f1524ab1432ac304?context=explore) we can see that it has as an entry point:
`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]` so if you will simply run `docker run -it --name test_conda continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest` you will be inserted into `bash` in that container.
If you are interested in running a different command in this docker container with an entry point run `docker run -it --entrypoint "the command you wish to run" continuumio/conda-ci-linux-64-python3.7:latest`. Overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` is something that has do be done explicitly in a `docker run` command.